# lock range of cells based on total sum of the range in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

How can I lock `AC10:AC69` and `AE10:AE69` range in google sheet, if sum of these 2 ranges is larger than or equal to 61 (>=61) ?

the 2 ranges are total pax of the booking each day:

```
AC10 - 2pax, 
AC11 - 13pax, 
AC12 - 1 pax, 
AE10 - 4pax, 
AE11 - 7pax, 
etc
```

Comment: i am not sure what do you mean by lock. preventing further editing? the "protect range" feature? and just confirming each row is one booking; but a booking might be for n pax

Answer (score 0):

ya. protect range if the total sum is more than 61. else if less than 61, we still can add in more pax for each row depend on booking. thanks